# Scala type constraints doesn't allow null

Tags: scala, types, null

I have the following Scala code:

```
class X[T1 <: AnyRef] {
   var _x : T1 = null 
}
```

The code _x = null is highlighted as error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Null(null)
required: T1
var _x : T1 = null : T1
```

If I add Null type constraint everything works fine. Why this happens? Scala defines AnyRef as equivalent of java.lang.Object, which is of course, nullable.

Comment: This is discussed in detail [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2206).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of

```
var _x : T1 = null
```

use

```
var _x : T1 = _
```

Explanation from the Scala Language Specification:

> A variable definition var x: T = _ can appear only as a member of a template. It introduces a mutable field with type T and a default initial value. The default value depends on the type T as follows:
>
> 0 if T is Int or one of its subrange types,
> 0L if T is Long,
> 0.0f if T is Float,
> 0.0d if T is Double,
> false if T is Boolean,
> () if T is Unit,
> null for all other types T.

Comment: Clearly that works. And _x of an instance of X is then null. Would you be able to explain what's going on here in some more detail?

Answer (score 10):

```
class X[T1 <: AnyRef] {
   var _x : T1 = null 
}
```

If you want it to be nullable, replace `T1 <: AnyRef` with `T1 >: Null`.

> Why this happens?

`Nothing` is a subtype of `AnyRef`, and `Nothing` is not nullable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enforce that the generic parameter must be nullable, then you can set a lower-bound to the Null type:

```
class X[T1 >: Null] {
   var _x : T1 = null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for completeness, using null in Scala is a bit discouraged. You normally wrap your variable in an Option as long as you do not have a good reason to use null. See [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) for more details.

Comment: I understand it, but we have to interoperate with Java code which uses nulls a lot.